# Want to Transfer an ImageView from one activity to another activity when clicked a button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have an `Activity` with 20 `ImageView` & buttons for each Image.
The button indicates that the IMAGE link with that button will added to favourite layout.
I Want to know that how to transfer that `ImageView` from this `Activity` to Favourite activity?
Should I create a `ListView` in Favourite `Activity` or Blank `ImageView`?
Please help me.

Comment: Do you have a link for every image>

Comment: No sir. There is no link.

Comment: I just paste image in Drawable folder and caste into ImageView..

Comment: please post some code or xml anything

Comment: yes please post some code for better understanding

Comment: You can create one global class and when you click on button that time store this clickable drawable value in global class variable and go to the other other activity and get image drawable from the global class.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want your image view to move around from the first activity into the second activity when launching it, kind of like what happens in the play store when you tap on an app and the logo of it moves from the row to the top of the apps own page, then android has something called `Shared Element Transition` and [This article should introduce you to it](https://medium.com/@aitorvs/android-shared-element-transitions-for-all-b90e9361507d).

However, if you wan't to save the image internally, to be remembered by the application that the user has favorited that specific image, then you should look into how to store data on Android then see [this guide by Google](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)